# Cannot start listener oracle 12c on RHEL 7.6

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle12c, rhel7

I installed Oracle Database on RHEL.7.6. However, after restart server, I cannot startup listener with command though Oracle Instance already been started. :

> lsnrctl start

It shows:

```
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/db1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/hungnv-fico1/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-01155: Incorrectly specified SID_LIST_LISTENER parameter in LISTENER.ORA
 NL-00305: the specified path name does not exist
```

This is my LISTENER.ORA file

> SID_LIST_LISTENER=
>   (SID_LIST=
>   (SID_DESC=
>   (GLOBAL_DBNAME=orcl)
>   (ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/12.2.0/db1)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)
>   )
>   )

My first thinking is that I was properly set the path wrongly. However, I've tried to:

```
echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/db1
```

[image]

Any idea for this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the variable in the LISTENER.ORA file. Specify the absolute path.

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER=(SID_LIST=(SID_DESC=(GLOBAL_DBNAME=orcl)(ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/db1)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))
```

Comment: Are you running `lsnrctl` as user `oracle`?

Comment: Take the SID_LIST section out completely.  It's only needed if you want to remotely connect to an idle instance.  In fact, you could probably delete (rename) the entire listener.ora file.  The listener doesn't require it.  Without listener.ora, the listener will quite happily start with all default values, and that is sufficient for the vast, vast majority of installations.

Comment: @TrippKinetics yes,